# What's the meaning of "fortified infraction restraint"?

Tags: star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

In *Solo: A Star Wars Story* (2018), Lando shows his Millennium Falcon to his new friends:

> Han: Looks like you had a little work done.
>
> Lando: Indeed I have, Han. Installed an escape pod in the mandible
>   notch,  alluvial dampers, a wet bar.
>
> BECKETT: And a **fortified infraction restraint** on the landing gear.

What's the meaning of "fortified infraction restraint"?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is the Star Wars version of a [Wheel Clamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_clamp) (Denver Boot) for starships

Lando's Millennium Falcon is impounded.

Answer (score 26):

This is further explained in *Solo: A Star Wars Story: Expanded Edition*, and in short it is a restraining bolt to keep the craft where it is, like a wheel clamp in our world.

> Han clears his throat. "Looks like you've had some work done," he said, stroking the metal shielding.
>
> "Indeed I have, Han," Lando said, still mispronouncing his name. "Two years restoring, retrofitting, adding features: customized flux regulator, new alluvial dampers, a wet bar..."
>
> "...a fortified infraction restrain on the landing gear?" Beckett added to the list from underneath, looking at the **ion restraining bolt** affixed to the front strut.
>
> Lando feigned surprise very poorly. "What is *that* doing there?"
>
> Beckett sighed. "Looks like someone fell behind on their docking fees," he said.
>
> <sub>*Solo: A Star Wars Story: Expanded Edition*</sub>

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the in-universe citations, unpacking the phrase might help.

[As @TheLethalCarrot's excerpt says](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/209235/whats-the-meaning-of-fortified-infraction-restraint/209236#209236), Lando has failed to pay his fees--an [*infraction*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infraction) (breaking a rule or agreement). Because of this, a *restraint* has been placed on the Millennium Falcon to prevent him from moving it until he pays: it's an *infraction restraint*.

Presumably it is *fortified* to make it strong enough to hold the craft (perhaps a landspeeder wouldn't need that).